# Is there a way to make this javascript animation more mobile friendly?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Well, I just learned to cache in javascript canvas yesterday, But i was learning it mainly for this code below. How do I even start? This seems to be way too complex to be efficient. My full code is here: https://github.com/GunZi200/Memory-Colour/blob/master/test.js

The code below works well, but redrawing everything at such a fast rate is just not good.

I would gladly like some advice on how to do this

```
var rects = [{x: 10 * Xf, y: 10 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#26A65B'},        //Green
        {x: 110 * Xf, y: 10 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#F22613'},          //Red
        {x: 10 * Xf, y: 130 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#1E90FF'},          //Blue
        {x: 10 * Xf, y: 250 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#F7CA18'},             //Gold
        {x: 110 * Xf, y: 250 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#8E44AD'},         //Purple
        {x: 210 * Xf, y: 10 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#DDA0DD'},          //Pink
        {x: 210 * Xf, y: 130 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#FF8C00'},         //Orange k6
        {x: 210 * Xf, y: 250 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: '#36D7B7'},   //Lightseagreen
        {x: 110 * Xf, y: 130 * Yf, w: xc, h: yc, color: 'Brown'}];          //Brown

var turnEvent = function turnEvent(AnX, AnY) { // AnX and AnY are x and y coordinates for clickevent
    console.time('Infunction');
    var lengd = rects.length;
    var i,
    one30 = 10,
    one40 = 10,  
    one301 = false, 
    one401 = false,
    temp = setInterval(myAnimation, 10);
    for (i = 0; i < lengd; i += 1) {
        if (collides([rects[i]], AnX, AnY)) {
            var rightBox = rects[i];
            var rectangle = rects2[i];
        }
    }
    rounded_rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, 90, 110, 10, 'black', 'black');
    function myAnimation() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = rightBox.color;
        ctx.moveTo((rectangle.x + 43 - one40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 33 - one30) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 50 + one40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 33 - one30) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 58 + one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 33 - one30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 58 + one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 43 - one40) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 58 + one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 70 + one40) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 58 + one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 78 + one30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 50 + one40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 78 + one30) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 43 - one40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 78 + one30) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 33 - one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 78 + one30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 33 - one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 70 + one40) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 33 - one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 43 - one40) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 33 - one30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 33 - one30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 43 - one40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 33 - one30) * Yf);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        if (one30 === 30) {
            one301 = true;
        } else {
            one30 += 2;
        }
        if (one40 === 40) {
            one401 = true;
        } else {
            one40 += 2;
        }
        if (one301 && one401) {
            rounded_rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, 90, 110, 10, null, 'black');
            console.timeEnd('Infunction');
            clearInterval(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what this code does, is it draws at first a 'smaller' rectangle, which is about third the size. Then with each Interval loop, the one30 and one40 are incremented by 2, increasing the size of the rectangle.

EDIT: Changed the question

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do there...

Comment: used original code, and 'trying' to explain below :P

Comment: Off topic, but the `i` variable used in the for-loop is not declared. This works in js, but implicitly makes the variable *global* (the variable will be bound to the global object, instead of to the local scope).

Comment: you should use `window.requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `setInterval()`

Comment: @micnic It doesn't seem very good. The first animation works, but is there no way to make it start over? I don't want to repaint the background again each loop, slows it just more down. The animation is : starts with a small rectangle and with each loop it gets bigger. second animation: background is not repainted as it should. so user just sees the end result

Comment: @GuðniMárGilbert, read how to use `window.requestAnimationFrame()`  here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/ , it is at the end of the article, but I guess the whole article will be useful for you. You'll need to make something like a recursive call to `window.requestAnimationFrame()` in side the animation function.

Comment: I'm with @micnic. There actually aren't too many useful situations for setInterval, as it doesn't really factor in time to execute the interval function itself, and can't be used to guarantee a certain rate of execution. Just run your function as often as possible, and calculate time-based effects from the amount of time that *has* passed.

Comment: Finally got it to work! :D Thank you guys. I used this article. http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ Works like a charm :)

Comment: setInterval is much faster? is this right? http://jsperf.com/animation123